# Instantiation of class - Spring framework

Tags: java, spring

In the below code,

1)
Create & initiate a new **dependency container** of implementation class(not yet instantiated). `appContext` gets the handle of that container.

```
ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Springbeans.xml");
```

2) Instantiate a class(with id `messagebean`), which is called bean. Using **service locator pattern** `mBean` gets the handle of that instance from the container.

```
MessageBean mBean = (MessageBean)appContext.getBean("messagebean");
```

3) 
Destroy all beans and close the dependency container.

```
(ConfigurableApplicationContext)appContext.close();
```

---

Below is the `messagebean` definition in `Springbeans.xml`

```
<beans ...>
    <bean id="messagebean" class="com.xyz.spring.MessageBean">
      <property name="message" value="hello" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

---

As per above understanding, Does implementation(`messagebean`) get instantiated after executing `getBean()`?

Answer (score 1):

The instantiation of the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext itself creates, autowires the beans and registers the listeners etc.

The call to ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(String location) in turn internally calls this method

```
/**
 * Create a new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext with the given parent,
 * loading the definitions from the given XML files.
 * @param configLocations array of resource locations
 * @param refresh whether to automatically refresh the context,
 * loading all bean definitions and creating all singletons.
 * Alternatively, call refresh manually after further configuring the context.
 * @param parent the parent context
 * @throws BeansException if context creation failed
 * @see #refresh()
 */
public ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(String[] configLocations, boolean refresh, ApplicationContext parent)
        throws BeansException {

    super(parent);
    setConfigLocations(configLocations);
    if (refresh) {
        refresh();
    }
}
```

If a bean is a prototype-scoped bean, then this call `appContext.getBean("messagebean");` will create a new bean, but it has various other conditions.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on bean scope.
Need to look at your **messagebean** definition.

by default bean scope is singleton and such bean will be created on context creation phase

```
ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Springbeans.xml");
```

and on this code line

```
MessageBean mBean = (MessageBean)appContext.getBean("messagebean");
```

you just get it from container.

for examaple, beans with prototype scope will be create by request

more info https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes

Comment: your bean scope is singleton, bean will create on  new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Springbeans.xml");

Comment: interface `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext` represents the Spring IoC container. When you say, *context creation phase*, do you mean, creation of Spring IOC container phase?

Comment: i mean , that such bean will create at time of context starting

Answer (score 1):

```
ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Springbeans.xml");
```

On the creating of the spring container, it reads the metadata either from XML configurations or from annotations. Based on the configurations it creates and manages beans life cycle. The beans configuration include their scope(singleton/prototype), default values etc.

```
MessageBean mBean = (MessageBean)appContext.getBean("messagebean");
```

This piece of code is just asking the spring IoC container that "Hey IoC container give me the bean with the name of messagebean".

By default, the scope of the bean is singleton i.e one per application. Scope can be configured in the Springbeans.xml file as

```
<beans ...>
<bean id="messagebean" class="com.xyz.spring.MessageBean">
  <property name="message" value="hello" scope = "singleton"/>
</bean>
```

Metadata can also be provided using annotations as

```
@Bean
@Scope("singleton")
public MessageBean getMessageBeanSingleton() {
  return new MessageBean("hello");
}
```

Comment: Does `getBean()` use service locator pattern to get the bean from container?

Comment: In the above code, Where is *Inversion of Control*?